# Do I have the guarantee that all pointers have the same size in bytes?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, architecture, sizeof

In C and C++, do I have the guarantee that all pointers have the same size in bytes, or in other words :

```
sizeof(void*) = sizeof(char*) = sizeof(int*) = ...
```

or there are some akward systems on which that is not true ?

Comment: I'll let someone else answer about the example you gave, but one that certainly may vary in C++ is `class Foo; sizeof(void (Foo::*)())`

Comment: @DarkFalcon Why might this vary?

Comment: @leemes: Because it is not a memory address. "The bottom line is that unlike a global function pointer, a member function pointer is not just the address of the first instruction of the function in most implementations" http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/function.html

Comment: It's not only their size you have to worry about. You need to worry about alignment requirements too (and possibly, bit representation).

Comment: They do on the same system.  All pointers are (in C, idk about C++ with the class pointers), the same for a given system.  Its because a pointer points to an address in memory. In a 32 bit system (4 bytes), it takes 4 bytes to address all regions of memory.  Therefore, a pointer to a value will be 4 bytes (since we only need 4 bytes to reach any address).  On 64, its typically 8 byte pointers(because we need twice as many bits to address all the memory!).  Some systems may vary though,  but this is the typical implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There is no guarantee in the standard.

There are some exception is some systems. Although it's fixed in many typical systems and depends on the architecture of that system. For example in 32-bit systems pointers are 4 bytes.

By the way, `uintptr_t` can hold pointers (Maybe we can assume it has the maximum size of a pointer in the current system):

> [`uintptr_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer)    unsigned integer type capable of holding a pointer

Comment: I know that 32 and 64 bits systems have oftenly different pointer size. But my question is not that. My question is : on a given architecture, do I have the guarantee that pointer to different types have the same size.

Comment: "No", even in a single given machine there is no guarantee.

Comment: It is not guaranteed that no pointer has size larger than `uintptr_t`. The standard guarantees that any pointer can be converted to `uintptr_t` and back. However, a pointer could have some expanded form for convenience (e.g., segment and offset), and converting it to `uintptr_t` could compress it to a canonical representation.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Very precision :-)  I think as a programmer it's easier to assume it's the maximum. I updated my answer to make it less certain.

Comment: @Vincent: 6.2.5/28, "A pointer to `void` shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as a pointer to a character type.48) Similarly, pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements. All pointers to structure types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as each other. All pointers to union types shall have the same representation and
alignment requirements as each other. Pointers to other types need not have the same representation or alignment requirements."